# How to consume rest service with basic auth from angular 6 securely

Tags: angular, rest, basic-authentication

I'm able to consume the REST API by passing the credentials in the HTTP headers. But the problem is that those credentials can be seen from developer tools and can be used to access the API directly.

So, we added reverse proxy configuration in IIS and used URL rewriting to pass the credentials. This solved the issue of open credentials from developer tools but we can still access the API because IIS is rewriting the URL if we invoke it directly in the browser.

What is the best approach to solving this issue?

Comment: You can't solve it. The client app runs in the user's browser - if *it* can make the requests, so can *they*. Why is it a problem that they can access the API directly, anyway?

Comment: But isn't this a trivial scenario? or is it like we should not consume any backend API from angular applications?

Comment: Isn't *what* a trivial scenario? And of course you can consume backend APIs from Angular apps, they are often very little use otherwise. But you shouldn't expose methods you wouldn't let the users call themselves (one obvious example: don't rely wholly on client-side validation).

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to consuming backend API. So if I understand correctly, you are saying like this consuming secure API should always be done from some server-side javascript rather than client-side like Angular application. Correct me if I understood it wrongly.

Comment: Well then how do you get the information from the server side JS to the client side?! I don't think you've quite got it.

Comment: yes, that was my next question if you have said yes. But then I don't understand what you were saying (you shouldn't expose methods you wouldn't let the users call themselves). All the invocations towards rest API can be seen in network log. Is there any way that we can hide the requests from getting logged?

Comment: No, thanks. And no, you can't hide the requests; that's not how single page/client side apps work.

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way. I need to pass basic auth credentials to access a REST API. What is the best approach to have this credentials in the application and pass it when required?